# Is there a way to format a JavaScript object logged to console in vscodes integrated git bash terminal?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal, javascript-objects, git-bash

I'm currently working with a an object and loading it into the terminal console with `console.log(books)`

The code for the object is this.

```
const books = [
  {
    id:1,
    name: "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",
    authorId: 1
  }, 
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",
    authorId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire",
    authorId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "The Fellowship of the Ring",
    authorId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "The Two Towers",
    authorId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "The Return of the King",
    authorId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "The Way of Shadows",
    authorId: 3
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Beyond the Shadows",
    authorId: 3
  },
];
```

It's quite a small problem, but I've noticed that not all of the information is displayed consistently when I log to console. Is this a problem with the git bash terminal or the integration between vscode and git bash and is there anything that can be done to make the presentation more consistent? It's a bit jarring.

[image: View of terminal]

I've tried looking for resources on this issue and haven't found anything similar. Would be great to get ideas as even if it's a small thing, when looking through larger data sets, it would be nice to know it will be formatted consistently.

Comment: Is this with console.log?

Answer (score 1):

I found a great answer to this on [Handy Tips on Using Console Log](https://dmitripavlutin.com/console-log-tips/#51-stringify-the-big-object)
You can use Stringify to structure big objects and create consistent formatting.

If I type the following it formats nicely.

```
  console.log(JSON.stringify(books, null, 2))
```